# Is there a 'standard' material icon to indicate that a view can be clicked on?

Tags: android

I have a view that spans an activity horizontally. It contains a text that is centered horizontally. The text is centered and could be of any length.
I'm looking for a suitable visual indicator that would clearly indicate that the view can be clicked-on. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Set an arrow icon next to the end of the screen like here

[image: Example]

Or just put the shadow under the view and make it look different than the other views.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`open_in_new`](https://material.io/icons/#ic_open_in_new) icon to signify that the text is clickable.